# Converting shell wildcards to regex

Tags: javascript, regex, wildcard

I want to search for titles using shell wildcards like `*.js`, `*.*.*` etc. in js. The thing is I loop through a list of titles and I need to filter the files using a js regex test. How do I convert shell wildcards to regex in a good way or are there any libraries that already does that?

Note: I want a generic converter from shell wildcards to regex.

Comment: Normally `*` is pretty much equivalent to `/.*/` and `.` stays `/./`

Comment: No, `*` is a short for `{0,}` in regex.

Comment: You should read more thoroughly... the question was about wildcards in a search. E.g. `*.js` would be `/.*\.js/` - `*` converts to `/.*/` here.

Comment: `*` in glob syntax (like `*.js`) is equivalent to `.*` in regex.

Comment: I think it was a misunderstanding it is not just `*.js` but all kinds of shell wildcards.

Comment: BTW this is more tricky than it looks because shell wildcards are path-aware.

Answer (score 19):

If you want a generic converter function, this should work:

```
function globStringToRegex(str) {
    return new RegExp(preg_quote(str).replace(/\\\*/g, '.*').replace(/\\\?/g, '.'), 'g');
}
function preg_quote (str, delimiter) {
    // http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
    // +   original by: booeyOH
    // +   improved by: Ates Goral (http://magnetiq.com)
    // +   improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +   bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
    // +   improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
    // *     example 1: preg_quote("$40");
    // *     returns 1: '\$40'
    // *     example 2: preg_quote("*RRRING* Hello?");
    // *     returns 2: '\*RRRING\* Hello\?'
    // *     example 3: preg_quote("\\.+*?[^]$(){}=!<>|:");
    // *     returns 3: '\\\.\+\*\?\[\^\]\$\(\)\{\}\=\!\<\>\|\:'
    return (str + '').replace(new RegExp('[.\\\\+*?\\[\\^\\]$(){}=!<>|:\\' + (delimiter || '') + '-]', 'g'), '\\$&');
}
```

(preg_quote function from here: http://phpjs.org/functions/preg_quote/).

Use:

```
var realRegex = globStringToRegex("2012-*-*.js"); //returns a RegExp object of /2012\-.*\-.*\.js/g
```

Here's a JS fiddle of it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/d5sdw/2/

You can then use the RegExp object to match:

```
if (yourString.match(realRegex)) { //do something
```

**Update**: Supports `?` for single wildcard character.

Basically all this does is convert the whole string to non regex, and then makes sure that `*` gets mapped to `.*` and `?` gets mapped to `.`, as they're the equivalent.

Comment: There's still the `?` character to replace.

Comment: lodash has a escapeRegExp function you can use in place of preg_quote if you're already using that lib. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#escapeRegExp

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty close.

```
yourVar.match(/.*\.js$/i)
```

meaning

- beginning of string is any character sequence `.*`
- followed by `.js` in the end `\.js$`
- do this case insensitive `/i`

Comment: i would not write `\.js$` since it won't match if there is accidently a whitespace after the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

if regexp used to get boolean result (when you don't need a match result), it is better to use **test** method.

`/.*\.js$/i.test(yourVar)`