# Wildcards in string equality testing

Tags: javascript, regex, wildcard, equality

How can I match a string with a template, where the template uses asteriskses (*) to specify a wildcard?

The wildcard should match any amount of characters, but should also be escapable (`\*` should not be detected as a wildcard)

For example, I should get these results using the wildcard function `wildCompare(string, template)` (just as an example)

```
t = "*have some bacon"
wildCompare("Here, have some bacon", t) // true
wildCompare("Can I have some bacon please", t) // false
wildCompare("have some bacon", t) // true
t = "* \*LOL\* *"
wildCompare("*LOL*", t) // false
wildCompare("Haha *LOL* .", t) // true
t = "hello"
wildCompare("Hi, hello", t) // false
wildCompare("hello, hi", t) // false
wildCompare("hello", t) // true
t = "j*t";
wildCompare("javascript", t) // true
wildCompare("jscript", t) // true
wildCompare("Javascript", t) // false
wildCompare("just out", t) // true
wildCompare("just out here", t) // false
```

I'm not very confident in regex, but I could imagine that some kind of code that loops over the characters in a string to see if it is a wildcard would work, however, I am not entirely sure how this could be implemented to work in the way specified above.

After [testing the two answers below](http://jsperf.com/wildcards-in-string-equality), the indexOf method created by Cerbrus seems to be the fastest, however, his implementation does not support escaping of wildcards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this works, if you ignore the need to escape the wildcard:

```
t = "I*have some bacon"
function wildCompare(string, search){
    var prevIndex = -1,
        array = search.split('*'), // Split the search string up in sections.
        result = true;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length && result; i++){ // For each search section
        var index = string.indexOf(array[i]); // Find the location of the current search section
        if(index == -1 || index < prevIndex){ // If the section isn't found, or it's placed before the previous section...
            return false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Results:

```
wildCompare("Here, have some bacon", t) // False
wildCompare("I would like to have some bacon please", t) // True
wildCompare("I have some bacon", t)) // True
```

The easiest way to work around the "Wildcard escaping" thing would be to make the wildcard a variable character:

```
function wildCompare(string, search, wildcard){
    var prevIndex = -1,
        sa = search.split(wildcard),
        // Etc
```

This way, you can specify what the wildcard character(s) are, allowing for a little more flexibility.

---

Disclaimer:
I'm sure there's plenty of reasons this code isn't "good", "efficient", or something like that, but it's a way it could be done. Also, it might return incorrect values in some cases.

---

[mrfishie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1629802/mrfishie) fixed the function for mutliple sequential wildcards:

```
function wildCompareNew(string, search) {
    var startIndex = 0, array = search.split('*');
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var index = string.indexOf(array[i], startIndex);
        if (index == -1) return false;
        else startIndex = index;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s35XY/)**

Comment: It seems to work pretty well for some tests I have done. Do you know of any cases where it returns incorrect values? Also, you can just return `true` at the end and remove the `result` variable, as you are never changing its value.

Comment: I suspect it might break when the search string contains 2 the same values, with something in between, like `"abc * def * abc"`, and I haven't tested multiple wildcards in a string, like this: `"abc***abc"`

Comment: I modified your code a bit to fix that issue - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s35XY/)

Comment: ([See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s35XY/)) I made use of the start index argument to `indexOf`

Comment: Thanks :D I've edited that into the answer, for future visitors :P

Answer (score 1):

As long as you include [`preg_quote` from PHPJS](http://phpjs.org/functions/preg_quote/) (to replace characters that shouldn't get replaced by regex, such as `.`), then you can do this in one line using regex. It will **also** ignore your escaped characters.

```
function preg_quote(str, delimiter) {
  //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/preg_quote/
  // original by: booeyOH
  // improved by: Ates Goral (http://magnetiq.com)
  // improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
  //   example 1: preg_quote("$40");
  //   returns 1: '\\$40'
  //   example 2: preg_quote("*RRRING* Hello?");
  //   returns 2: '\\*RRRING\\* Hello\\?'
  //   example 3: preg_quote("\\.+*?[^]$(){}=!<>|:");
  //   returns 3: '\\\\\\.\\+\\*\\?\\[\\^\\]\\$\\(\\)\\{\\}\\=\\!\\<\\>\\|\\:'

  return String(str)
    .replace(new RegExp('[.\\\\+*?\\[\\^\\]$(){}=!<>|:\\' + (delimiter || '') + '-]', 'g'), '\\$&');
}

function wildCompare(str, search) {
    return str.match(new RegExp('^' + preg_quote(search).replace(/\\\*/g, '.*').replace(/\\\.\*/g, '\*') + '$')) !== null;
}
```

Please note that in order to escape a character you need to use `\\*` instead of `\*` (as the latter escapes the `*` and turns into `*` before we can do anything.

Comment: What if I use question marks? Will they act as wildcards too?

Comment: @mrfishie They'll get replaced by `preg_quote`, so no. Do you want that?

Comment: Good. All of the implementations I have seen allow question marks as wildcards

Comment: @mrfishie It sounds like raw regex rather than escaping the characters. `?` in regex usually means "the previous character/group is optional".

Comment: [One implementation I saw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818186/) allowed the use of the `?` even though it was using the `preg_quote` function. I'm not sure if it was on purpose or not.

Comment: @mrfishie You most likely hit [another answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13818704/247893), yes? The question mark was specifically added as you can see in the update as a user requested it (check out the comments).

Comment: Ahh, I didn't notice it was by you.. To me it looked like it wasn't handling the `?` and you put the message there to show that the `?` works.

Comment: @mrfishie Ah no, but I was actually looking for the answer when I wanted to write your answer. It was just quicker to rewrite than to bother to look up. :-)

Comment: The other implementation by Cerbrus seems to be the fastest, so I am going to go with that one for now. However, his version doesn't feature the escaping, so brownie points for that ;)